# Find the minimum of a concave function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, convex

I have proved that my function with two variable is concave. I am looking for the minimum of the function. Since the function is continuous over a convex set the minimum should occur on the border of the function. How can I find the minimum efficiently having these information?

Comment: Find the solutions to satisfy the KKT condition.
This solutions are local optima in constraint problems.

Comment: 1) this is better suited to operations research SE 2) this is a tough problem in general: we can experience multiple optima on the boundary. Is there a natural way to parameterize points on the boundary of your convex set? If so, you can proceed by defining a separate optimization problem only defined on the boundary. For more specific advice, we may need more details. The fact that you're only in two dimensions might save you.

Comment: see also https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01589330